# How does Undertale on PS4 handle multiple user accounts?

Tags: ps4, undertale

How does Undertale on PS4 handle multiple user accounts? If one user has already gotten one ending, will that impact another user who is starting the game for the first time?

Comment: I can at least confirm that, like many downloadable games for PS4, the game itself can only be launched by a user with a license for it--i.e., the user who purchased it. Presumably multiple users could buy it and we could test this scenario, but for now it is unlikely to apply since in most cases only one user will own it.

Answer (score 2):

Each account uses its own save file so they should not impact each other.